# Is it possible for git to track underscore folders/files?

Tags: git

I tried to use some folders with underscore and even when i commit the changes, I found there are no underscore folders in my git.

Comment: Are the folders empty? Git cannot track empty folders, only files. You need to add at least one file (e.g. a hidden file `.gitkeep`)

Comment: Underscores are not special to git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing special about the underscore character in filenames to Git. *However*, that said, Git does not allow to track empty directories.

There are at least two workarounds which might or might not fit your requirements:

1. Add a hidden file to the directory (e.g. `.gitkeep` or an empty `.gitignore`) which can be tracked
2. Add a script which will create the empty directories. Calls this script after initial clone or when changing branches.

Comment: I suggest that creating a hidden file is much simpler and less error-prone. I'd resort to a script only if the directory really really has to exist *and* be completely empty.

Comment: @KeithThompson: yes, I agree. But sometimes directories really have to be empty. Certain software won't work properly with (hidden) files in those directories. In that case either manually creating them or via script is the only option I see (with the scripting option being the convenient and less error prone)

Comment: Certainly a script is less error-prone that doing it (*shudder*) manually. I suspect that in most cases, if an empty directory is required, it's needed in the installation directory, not in the git repo, so you can create it in a build or installation script.